# Cast int to decimal(18,18)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to insert the value 10 into column1 with a datatype decimal(18,18).

> Insert into table column1 values 10

Gives the error **Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric**

If I attempt to cast

```
select cast(10 as decimal(18,18))
```

I get the same error **Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.**

I have also attempted

```
select cast(cast(10 as float) as decimal(18,18))
```

and get the same error.

How can I cast the value 10 to decimal(18,18)?

Comment: It works with decimal(20, 18) and decimal (18,16) - so when the last is less than the first by 2 or more. That's strange as MSDN allows it 0 <= s <= p.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Decimal (18, 18)` has eighteen places to the right of the decimal point and none to the left. 10 won't fit.